# What's the answer to this?

Tags: cipher

I've been sent this yesterday with no info and I'm so confused. Can anyone tell me what the message is?

Seh gdyla wdhjh, seh qhun alts bhn hqhunxyh plt axxbdyf gxu plt yhqhu gxryi lyi tx seh wrmmah khjlzh rytxaqlkah. 
Pdsedy sexth pex jelaahyfhi ds, sexth ghp gduts, plt yx axyfhu l yhhi gxu jdwehut. 
Sexth pex jelaahyfhi ds phuh seh gduts sx uhladmh sels sehuh plt yx pxui sels jxrai kh rthi sx ihjdwehu:

Rlx tusmoik jmioik ivhrig hrw hrhalxy wxjvxa vxcitsiw

Answer (score 4):

> Rlx tusmoik jmioik ivhrig hrw hrhalxy wxjvxa vxcitsiw

> [Vigenere cipher](https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/vigenere-cipher) with key "the". Old school solvers might assume one of the words is "cipher" and see the key fragment "etheth".
>
> > Yet another cipher broken and another secret revealed

Answer (score 3):

Using a substitution solver for monoalphabetic ciphers, we get this:

> The final cieme, the very last key everyone was looking for was never found and so the cuzzle bemaje unsolvable. Within those who mhallenged it, those few first, was no longer a need for michers. Those who mhallenged it were the first to realize that there was no word that mould be used to demicher:
> Uao srtzqdb mzdqdb dpeudf euc euelaon compol poxdstdc

Obviously, this isn't perfect, but readable, so the actual probably says:

> The final piece, the very last key everyone was looking for was never found and so the puzzle became unsolvable. Within those who challenged it, those few first, was no longer a need for ciphers. Those who challenged it were the first to realize that there was no word that could be used to decipher:

Since we don't have the full alphabet used in the above paragraph, we can make only educated guesses as to what that last line becomes...

> Uao srtzqdb czdqdb dpeudf eup euelaon pocpol poxdstdp

Comment: It's a rotational 13 with a reversed alphabet.

Comment: @LeppyR64 - Oh, I'll try that, then!

Comment: @LeppyR64 - I tried that and it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: I meant for the first step. That gives you the full alphabet.  How to do the second step is still a mystery.

Comment: @LeppyR64 - That could be interesting. I'll try.

Comment: @LeppyR64 - No, I meant that the original text doesn't contain all the characters in the alphabet so we can't tell what the final line should truly be...

Comment: No but it contains enough to show clearly the pattern used.  Cryptogram solvers are spoiling you.  If you had to do it by hand you would see the pattern.